# Cut rod at two points and one piece length greater than L

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We have a S cm long stick.It can be broken only at certain positions.We want to calculate the number of GOOD Pairs. It satisfies the following conditions

1. A good pair consists of 2 distinct positions where the stick can be broken.
2. When the stick is broken at these two positions there should be at least one stick with length strictly greater than L.

Now we are given  S,Length of the stick let it be 10,total no. of locations where the stick can be broken N (say 3) . Let the points be [1,3,9] . And let L be 5 then here answer is 3

```
Pair 1 : [1,9] 
Pair 2 : [1,3]
Pair 3 : [3,9]
```

If we cut at any of the pairs then their will always be piece with length greater than L.

I need to count the pairs only. We can't go for each of N^2 pairs. I think their must be some DP approach for it. Please help to solve this problem

**Constraints** :

```
3<=S<=5*10^4
2<=N<= MIN(S-1,10^4)
0<=L<=S-1
All Array element are distinct and 1<=A[i]<=S-1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your points.

**Intuition**

If a pair of consecutive elements `(i, i + 1)` are valid cut points because `A[i + 1] - A[i] > L` then so are all the points after `i + 1` combined with `i` and those before `i` combined with `i + 1`, for the same reason.

Also add one for the cases `A[i] > L` and `S - A[i + 1] > L`.

**Generalization**

If two consecutive points are not good, then you'd need to check `(i, i + 2)`, then `(i, i + 3)` etc. To do this efficiently, for each `i`, binary search for the first point after it that is good:

```
A[i + k] - A[i] > L
=>
A[i + k] > L + A[i]
```

So binary search for the smallest `A[i + k]` larger than `L + A[i]`.

Comment: @nwellnhof - I generalized it.

Comment: @IVlad How binary search ? Please add a pseudocode to make things clear

Comment: @user3840069 - no, I won't. You keep asking these questions and expect to be delivered the full solution on a platter each and every time. I'm not doing it this time.

Comment: @IVlad If am not wrong you are saying something like this : long long ans=0;
     sort(cutPoints.begin(),cutPoints.end());
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            int search=L+cutPoints[i];                                       ans+=upper_bound(cutPoints.begin(),cutPoints.end(),search)-cutPoints.begin();
  }